# In Powershell I get access denied with New-Object IO.FileStream but I have access

Tags: powershell, permissions, attachment, sharepoint-list

I try to attach files to listitems in sharepointlists. Therefore I want to use the following code in the Powershell:

```
$Path = "\\server\share\folder\file.jpg"
$File = New-Object IO.FileStream($Path,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
```

I get the following error

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Access to the path '\\server\share\folder\file.jpg' is denied."
At line:1 char:70
+ ... US'; $var = New-Object IO.FileStream("\\server\share\folder\file.jpg ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

When I simply type `\\server\share\folder\file.jpg` in the same powershell the file will open and I see the picture. Where am I getting wrong? Or is there some completely different approach?

Comment: if you type "$file.Dispose()" and re-run your script, you also have the error ?

Comment: You are opening the file in `ReadWrite` mode. Try `New-Object IO.FileStream($Path,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open,[System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)`.

Comment: $file.Dispose() does not help.

Comment: Yeah, ```[System.IO.FileAccess]::Read``` helps! Thank you JosefZ

Answer (score 1):

Thank you JosefZ,
Adding `[System.IO.FileAccess]::Read` to the command was successfull. As I have only read-permissions to the share, the file must be opened in read-only mode.

The code must be as following:

```
$Path = "\\server\share\folder\file.jpg"
$File = New-Object IO.FileStream($Path,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open,[System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
```